# Have ServerSocket accepting connection, want to close dialog when connected

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, runnable

I have a simple server-client program set up. The user starts listening for a connection and a dialog appears with the message "Listening for connection" and a Cancel button. If he hits cancel, the server socket is closed. That's all fine.

What I want is to make the "Listening..." dialog disappear when a connection is made.

Currently the ListenDialog is a runnable, as I've tried putting the `accept()` in there, or a `while(true), if socket != null, dispose();...` nothing has worked. The dialog is set as Modal, because otherwise the `accept()` blocks and the dialog GUI (i.e. cancel button) is never drawn; even the `run()` method never runs until after the `accept()` stops blocking, even though it seems like it should be in a separate thread.

So, I can get the closing functionality I want by just putting `dispose()` in the dialog's `run()` method and making the dialog non-modal... but it will never paint the GUI so the cancel button can't be used. I can get my GUI and cancel button by making the dialog modal, but even after the `accept()` stops blocking the `run()` method doesn't seem to do anything (i.e. the dialog just sits there until manually closed, not even the `run()` code plays out.)

Please tell me there's something obvious I'm missing!

```
ListenDialog listener = new ListenDialog();

Thread listenThread = new Thread(listener);
listenThread.start();

try {
    socket = server.accept();
    listener.dispose();
} catch(IOException e1) {
    addMessage("Accept Failed: " + e1.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: If the `listenThread` does nothing but use the listener, why not just kill it after the socket is bound?

Comment: Have you tried using an AsyncTask or something similar? I guess you shouldn't be accepting sockets on the gui thread ...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not 100% sure how this solution worked or what the important difference was from any of the other things I tried... but here it is.

The constructor for the `ListenDialog` now contains the creation of a new thread for itself. The `run()` method contains the `accept()` call followed by a `dispose()` outside the try/catch block. All of the code shown above (except the creation of the new `ListenDialog`) has been moved into the `ListenDialog` class.